Array formula returns data from SECOND relevant row, can't get first row
I want to copy, from a source sheet, select columns (h,f,e,g,k) out of relevant rows (relevant rows have column B entry that matches destination sheet A1/"title")
The formula I am using seems to skip the first row of relevant data.  Can't figure out why.
Source sheet has header on row 1, data starts on row 2.  Destination sheets have Sheet Title on row 1, header on row 2, then data gets copied in starting on row 3.
Source Sheet ('Paste-Data'):



ID
NAME
TYPE
STYLE
MOD
MFR
DESC
QTY
COST
MAR
PRI




1
JOE
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1


2
JOE
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
2


3
JOE
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3
3


4
BOB
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4


5
BOB
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5
5



Formula in cell B3 on destination sheet:

=IFERROR(INDEX('Paste-Data'!$B$1:$K$4000,SMALL(IF('Paste-Data'!$B$1:$B$4000=$A$1,ROW('Paste-Data'!$B$1:$B$4000)),ROWS($H$1:$H2)),7),"")

this should take the QTY from column H on the source sheet and put it in column B on the destination sheet.
Formula in cell E3 on destination sheet:

=IFERROR(INDEX('Paste-Data'!$B$1:$K$4000,SMALL(IF('Paste-Data'!$B$1:$B$4000=$A$1,ROW('Paste-Data'!$B$1:$B$4000)),ROWS($G$1:$G2)),6),"")

this should take the DESC from column G on the source sheet and put it in column E on the destination sheet.
Destination Sheets current results:



JOE






ID
QTY
MFR
MOD
DESC
PRI




i
2
2
2
2
2


ii
3
3
3
3
3


iii











BOB






ID
QTY
MFR
MOD
DESC
PRI




i
4
4
4
4
4


ii








Destination Sheets desired results:



JOE






ID
QTY
MFR
MOD
DESC
PRI




i
1
1
1
1
1


ii
2
2
2
2
2


iii
3
3
3
3
3






BOB






ID
QTY
MFR
MOD
DESC
PRI




i
4
4
4
4
4


ii
5
5
5
5
5




Why not just use the FILTER function?

I am not sure why you don't use FILTER. (maybe you don't have MS365).
But you can put below formula in B3:
=IFERROR(INDEX('Paste-Data'!$A$1:$K$4000, SMALL(IF('Paste-Data'!$B$2:$B$4000 = $A$1, ROW('Paste-Data'!$B$2:$B$4000)),ROW(H1:H6)), {1,8,6,5,7,11}),"")

Row number you want to select:
SMALL(IF('Paste-Data'!$B$2:$B$4000 = $A$1, ROW('Paste-Data'!$B$2:$B$4000)), ROW(H1:H6))

Column number you want to select:
{1, 8, 6, 5, 7, 11}
Result look like this:


Awesome, thank you.  I will try this and let you know!

Your formula uses ROW not ROWS, and your line number starting on $B$2 instead of $B$1 in SMALL( has fixed my issue.
I couldn't get the column select array to work, instead of {1,4,7,etc}, I had to put the exact column number to pull from in each dest column.  Not sure what the difference is or how you got the result you showed.  It did not seem to work for me that way.
In the end, my finished formula for B3:
=IFERROR(INDEX('Paste-Data'!$B$1:$K$4000,SMALL(IF('Paste-Data'!$B$2:$B$4000=$A$1,ROW('Paste-Data'!$B$2:$B$4000)),ROW($H1:$H$4000)),7)&"","")

You don’t have MS365? If not, selecting multiple rows and columns probably won’t work for you. Or did you try to input it as an array formula? using crtl + shift+enter? I don’t have a pre 365  Excel so I cannot verify myself.

If you are on MS365 desktop, you don't need to use ctrl+shift+enter. Just put formula in B3, it would spill. Have you ever tried using index to select several rows and columns? very easy way to test is =INDEX('Paste-Data'!A1:K6,{1;2},{3,4}). Here is what it looks like:https://i.imgur.com/PF7a4nU.png (I am on Excel for Mac Version 16.86 (24042911), but I am sure what works on mac would work on Windows)

I am also trying to not just grab entire columns, I used array function because I needed to only pull data that matches criteria in that NAME column.... I am looking at the FILTER function now.  It looks like it is not capable of re-arranging the columns, it is one of those new Spill-type functions... if my source data and destination data matched it would be great, but i can't figure out how to rearrange a FILTER.

maybe the key info i left out is the source data is going to change frequently - I never now how many rows of each "Name" column I am going to have.  My goal is to have several sheets, each with a Name, and for each sheet to only copy the rows with the matching name, and also to only copy the columns I want, and to rearrange those columns... perhaps more complex than ideal, but I am trying to take export data from one software and auto-format it to be taken in by another software.

Use HSTACK to re-arrange your columns, and then use FILTER on top of the re-arranged columns. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hstack-function-98c4ab76-10fe-4b4f-8d5f-af1c125fe8c2

What about this?

Formula in cell B16 is:
=INDEX($C$1:$K$6;MATCH(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-2-LEN($A16));$B$1:$B$6;0)-1+LEN($A16);MATCH(B$15;$C$1:$K$1;0))

This will return the desired output as you wish for any user (Joe, Bob).
You need to notice 2 things:

This formula will work only if your data is sorted as in provided input (by name and ID)
It uses INDIRECT which is a volatile function so if you use it heavily it may overcharge your worksheets.

